# Hibernate with Springs .hbm.xml filenotfoundException

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am using netbeans IDE, I am integrating hibernate with springs. I am getting the following exception when I run the program:

```
Exception while loading the app : java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [Employee.hbm.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
```

This my **applicationContext**.**xml** file:

```
 <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!-- was: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> -->
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">


    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">      
        <property name="driverClassName"  value="org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver"></property>  
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/sample"></property>  
        <property name="username" value="app"></property>  
        <property name="password" value="app"></property>      
    </bean>



    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>  

        <property name="mappingResources">
            <list>
                <value>Employee.hbm.xml</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">  
            <props>  
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.DerbyDialect</prop>  
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>  
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>  

            </props>  
        </property>  

    </bean>

    <bean id="template" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTemplate">  
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"></property>  
    </bean>  



    <bean class="com.office.businessLayer.Security" id="security">
    </bean>


    <bean id="dao" class="com.office.dao.EmployeeDao">
        <property name="template" ref="template"/>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

I have tried every possible solution on the internet but the exception still remains. Can somebody please help with this?

This is the project directory:

[image: Directory]

Comment: where is your **`Employee.hbm.xml`** file located ???

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of your project directory ?

Comment: ok give me a second

Comment: move your emplyee.hbm.xml file to the directory where Employee model is present and use <mapping resource="org/yourpackagename/Employee.hbm.xml"/> instaed of <property name="mappingResources">
            <list>
                <value>Employee.hbm.xml</value>
            </list>
        </property> and try

Comment: @Vaibs it says invalid content was found starting mapping should add some schema or something

Answer (score 0):

if your employee.hbm.xml is at root of application, your mapping resource should be something like this.

```
<property name="mappingResources">
    <list>
        <value>classpath:Employee.hbm.xml</value>
    </list>
</property>
```

Comment: NO its not working. my Employee.hbm.xm is in web-inf file

Comment: Move your Employee.hbm.xml to source folder

Comment: i moved it to default package under source folder

Comment: once you have compiled you should see Employee.hbm.xml insdie yoru /WEB-INF/classes folder

Comment: I am really sorry I am not able to find any web-inf/classes folder even after compilation

Answer (score 0):

Put your `Employee.hbm.xml` file in the same package that `Employee.java` resides and leave your `mappingResources` config as is (`<value>Employee.hbm.xml</value>`).